# Material Change Problems Unity 3D. Cant see any errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3D in C# and am trying a simple script to change the material of an object. The initial material set works, but the change on the click of it does not do anything.
I know this is basic, and there are lots of questions on this topic here already, but all of them that i have seen, i have tried and not worked.
The program does not throw back any errors, the material simply does not change. i tried it with a texture instead and even a renderer.material.color at one point just to see if my files had problems. On the if statements i have tried == and =.

please help me find what I've done wrong, even if its a small typo i cant seem to see one.

here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class tilechange : MonoBehaviour {

public Material Grey;
public Material Black;

void Start()
{
    renderer.material = Grey;
}


void OnMouseDown () {
    if (renderer.material = Grey)
    {
        renderer.material = Black;
    }
    if (renderer.material = Black)
    {
        renderer.material = Grey;
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

---

Update

I have added lots of debug.logs and it appears that the colour changes, then changes back. do you know how i could stop this happening?

here is a gif starting on grey and clicking. http://gyazo.com/7c556ea79bb9b7277ae23d14ee44f8d2

here is a gif starting on black and clicking. http://gyazo.com/c6e00d858ab8d47436e689dd124bd762

they both act differently, which seems like it could be something to do with the problem

---

Further Update

I tried adding in a third material and experimenting with the order of the if statements, the program runs through all of them, even if the materials are not used. and the material once clicked on always becomes that of the one in the last if statement.

Comment: Add your Render code, here we can't see anything

Comment: i can see it? (assume what i have is what you mean). here is an image link to a screenshot? http://gyazo.com/7ba4c3f80d8a4fcd07436e8a6ce78648

Comment: Have you confirmed that OnMouseDown is being executed when you click on it? Try adding a print statement inside it to verify. Do you have a collider attached to the object?

Comment: I just tried a debug.log and it is registering my click. i do have a mesh collider on the object if that is what you mean.

Comment: okay i just added more debug.logs. it appears that the colour changes, then changes back very quickly. do you know how i could change this?

Comment: @McGlovin I'm not sure why the color would change back. Is there anything else in the scene that changes the material?

Comment: no the script is the only thing. but thsis problem only occurs when the colour is grey. if it starts off black it changes to grey, but then not back again ever. and if it starts off grey it doesnt change?

Comment: the texture you are using for the ground is really similar to the one I made for an Android game a few months ago: [Hexa](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.letiagoalves.hexa)

Comment: @letiagoalves that is quite cool, i shall download it and have a play later ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your updated code is using assignment instead of testing for equivalence.

```
if (renderer.material = Grey)
{
    renderer.material = Black;
}
if (renderer.material = Black)
{
    renderer.material = Grey;
}
```

Should be:

```
if (renderer.material == Grey)
{
    renderer.material = Black;
}
if (renderer.material == Black)
{
    renderer.material = Grey;
}
```

Comment: when i change the code to ==, still nothing happens, as said in the question i have tried both

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've assigned the material color correctly, since you've created materials, but haven't set any properties on those materials.

See [Unity documentation for SetColor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html)

(Edit: Make sure to select 'C#' from the top right)

(Edit2)
Based on your updated question, I believe it's changing -> changing back because it's registering multiple mousedown events. Try adding a tick to delay as a minimum before changing the color back

See the [Unity topic that is related](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/519422/how-to-avoid-multiple-mouse-clicks-registering-in.html)

Comment: the materials are all set correctly in the visual editor, with textures assigned. the materials both work on start, just dont change.

Comment: I don't have unity available to open right this moment, but try renderer.material.SetColor(Grey.GetColor)

Comment: i have updated the question now, i have found out that the colour is chnaging, but it then instantly changes back. but thank you

Comment: Updated my answer based on your updated information.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I'm answering for the sake of anyone landing here.  The problem is the two if statements.  They both get executed so they are canceling each other out.  You need to use an "else if" for the second one so it only gets executed if the first one isn't.  This should accomplish what you are wanting, switching the material.

```
if (renderer.material == Grey) {
    renderer.material = Black;
} else if (renderer.material == Black) {
    renderer.material = Grey;
}
```